# Trying to load and use a dll file in python properly

Tags: python, c++, windows, ctypes

I am trying to load and use a dll in python. I have been trying to use [windows-kill](https://github.com/alirdn/windows-kill) but I don't know much at all about C++. I was able to compile it fine in visual studio and the exe file works fine but I'd like to figure out how to load the dll with Python so I can learn how to load other dll's that I may want to use  eventually.
So far this is the code I have come up with. I wasn't sure if it needed SIGINT or a number for the value because the command line uses -SIGINT but I have been trying both.

```
lib = ctypes.CDLL('windows-kill-library.dll')
libOpen = getattr(lib, "?sendSignal@WindowsKillLibrary@@YAXKK@Z")
libOpen.argtypes = [wintypes.DWORD, wintypes.DWORD]
val = 'SIGINT'
# val = 0
l = libOpen(9844, val)
print(l)
```

Using SIGINT as the val I get the error:

```
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 2: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type
```

and using a number as a value I get:

```
OSError: [WinError -529697949] Windows Error 0xe06d7363
```

I know the argtypes must be wrong or something but I have been trying lots of different things and getting the same errors.

This is the undecorated name:

```
void WindowsKillLibrary::sendSignal(unsigned long,unsigned long)
```

I have tried using ctypes.c_ulong and some others for the argtypes but still get the same errors.

In visual studio when I hover over DWORD in the 2 lines below:

```
DWORD signal_type;
DWORD signal_pid;
```

It says "typedef unsigned long DWORD" if that helps.

Here is also the usage example that can be found [here](https://github.com/alirdn/windows-kill/tree/master/windows-kill-library)

```
/// <summary>
/// Sends the signal.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="signal_pid">The signal target process id.</param>
/// <param name="signal_type">The signal type.</param>
void sendSignal(DWORD signal_pid, DWORD signal_type);
```

Does anyone know how I can make this work? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're needing a DLL because Windows doesn't have a native `signal` facility, so the library is emulating the POSIX `signal` functionality. POSIX `SIGINT` is the numeric value 2, which is a perfectly fine value for the `DWORD`. That constant 2 is conveniently available as `signal.SIGINT.value`.

Comment: Yeah, I just keep getting this error though `OSError: [WinError -529697949] Windows Error 0xe06d7363`. I think I am doing it wrong. In my code above I have `ctypes.CDLL` when I believe it should be `ctypes.WinDLL` but I get the same error either way. I'll have to keep messing with it until I figure out how to do it properly.